# What happens if the card to be copied and bounced by Sublime Epiphany is the same?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Sublime Epiphany](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSublime%20Epiphany%5d) and both bounce my Frilled Mystic and copy it, what happens. Given that the bouncing is listed first on the card, does the copying ability still see the Frilled Mystic in a way that allows it to create the copy?

Answer (score 4):

From the Rulings in [the Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=485397)

> If you choose the third and fourth modes and target the same creature you control both times, you’ll return it and then create a token that’s a copy of it, using its copiable values as it last appeared on the battlefield. This is because the legality of targets is checked only as the spell begins to resolve, before any actions are performed.